# How to Remove default "Login" link

Tags: login

[image]

1. I created a website using Wordpress.
2. But unable to Remove the Default "Login" Link using dashboard.
3. Is there any code to remove this feature, so that i can access the dashboard directly
   using wp-admin url

Comment: this is probably prt of your theme and you will need to ask the author of the theme.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to ask the theme author about this.

If you would like to try fix this yourself, the code for this will probably be located in header.php, just do a search for "log in" and remove/comment out the markup/function that places it there.